# Coloursquare Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, colors, hsl

I'm writing a colourpicker in Javascript and having some degree of progress. However, I've noticed that the algorithm I am using to generate the colour space could be improved in order to fill the space more efficiently.

I'm using HSL to generate the current map and below is an example.

[image]

I'm increasing lightness along the Y-axis and increasing saturation along the X-axis but I've noticed that other colour pickers seem to use a more efficient model, such as the one below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [webresourcesdepot.com](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/javascript-color-picker.jpg))</sub>

My colourspace has a bias to white colours and could be used more efficiently to show red colours.

On the second space, saturation seems to increase across the X-axis and lightness increases along the Y-axis, however the top right corner is fully saturated without being fully light.

How is the second space generated?

Comment: Your color picker is wrong. Have a look at mozilla's color picker for hue = 87 and you'll see x=saturation / y=lightness produces a different result (with more colors available).  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Outil_Selecteur_Couleurs_CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use HSB instead of HSL if you want your color picker to behave like the one you showed.